# Trying to swap strings in C?

Tags: c

I'm taking 2 character arrays as parameters and trying to swap those. This is what I have so far, but I'm getting the error "array initializer must be an initializer list". Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here's my code so far for the function:

```
void swapStrings(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    char tempString[] = string1;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting that line of code to do? Are you expecting it to allocate an object on the stack? How large are you expecting that object to be? Are you expecting `string1`'s contents to be copied in? Are you expecting the fact that you named these things with names that start with "string", the compiler will know they're strings, and treat them that way and not just like arrays of characters?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `tempString` and then use something like `strcpy()` to copy `string1` to `tempString`

Comment: Note that your function parameters are really pointers. C syntax is funny like that.

Answer (score 1):

The first concern is to make sure that the two strings both have enough space to be swapped.

You can see the problem with trying to swap `"Hello"` with `"ThisIsAVeryLongStringThatWillNotFitInTheSpaceOfHello"`; there just isn't enough space in the first buffer to hold the second buffer.

Assuming there is enough space, you just need to swap every character, one-by-one until the entire strings are swapped.

```
void swapStrings(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    char temp;
    do
    {
        temp = *string1;
        *string1 = *string2;
        *string2 = temp;
    } while(*string1++ && *string2++);

    // At this point, the shorter string is done swapping.
    // But we need to finish swapping the longer string:

    if (*string1)
    {
        while (*string2++ = *string1++) ; 
    }
    if (*string2)
    {
        while (*string1++ = *string2++) ; 
    }
}
```

***Note*** contrary to the answer by `cdonts`, no third buffer needs to be allocated or managed.  The memory requirement is much smaller because there is only a single byte needed for swapping the strings.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can't copy strings using the assignment operator, so you'll probably want something like this.

```
size_t length = strlen(string1) + 1;
char *tempString = malloc(length);
strncpy(tempString, string1, length);
free(tempString);
```

(Assuming both strings have enough space to be swapped as @abelenky said.)

Hope it helps!